# How can i disable a Button in angular based on value or no value in form

Tags: angular

I have 2 cases where I need to be able to determine if a button should be enabled or not.

1. In case one my table has a value of status {{ survey.status }} and if the value of it is either "new" or "pending" I want to have the button enabled. for all other values it should be disabled.
2. The second case is where I have an email field {{ survey.email }} if that field is blank / empty I want to have the email button disabled as there is no way to send email if you don't have an address.

This what my 2 button look like right now

```
<button type="button" (click)="emailSurvey(survey.docId)" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><span class="fa fa-envelope-open-o"></span></button>
<button type="button" (click)="deleteSurvey(survey.docId)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<button [disabled]="!(survey.status == 'new' || survey.status == 'pending')">
</button
```

Comment: Works for me, you might just want to edit response and correct the 'new' you have a double quote which causes a exception

Comment: Was a typo. Corrected. If this helped, please accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

For scenario one : [disabled]="!(survey.status === 'new' || survey.status === 'pending')"

```
<button type="button" [disabled]="!(survey.status === 'new' || survey.status === 'pending')"  (click)="deleteSurvey(survey.docId)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></button>
```

For the second scenario : [disabled]="!(survey.email === '')"

```
 <button type="button" [disabled]="!(survey.email === '')" (click)="emailSurvey(survey.docId)" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><span class="fa fa-envelope-open-o"></span></button>
```